# Is there a way to get flexbox to work with Django?

Tags: html, css, django, flexbox, django-templates

I've imported the latest bootstrap stylesheets and placed them in my homepage.html file, however, when trying to work with the css and actually styling it, it seems to completely ignore flexbox commands which I thought bootstrap 4 already has? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Django cannot possibly affect your use of flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

I have used it with Django nicely. THis should be layout for bootstrap's flex to work

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This will set layout that  has 2 columns. Both have 50% width of parents. Don't put your style on bootstrap's components. It will msot likely break everything because they have their own style by default. For me this worked nicely..

If it doesn't work for you post some code so we can see it